# softlayer api: reload os with provate image failed:Selected image is incompatible with this guest

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I used `virtual_guest.verifyReloadOperatingSystem(reload_config,id=instance_id)` to do check before executing `reload api`. `verifyReloadOperatingSystem` raise exception as:

> SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Selected image is
>   incompatible with this guest.

Could you tell me What is the cause of this problem?

p.s..

```
reload_config = {
            'imageTemplateId': image_id
        }
```

Comment: This question shows no research effort. See [Ask]

Comment: before trying to do something using the API you need to make sure that what you want to do is possible using the control portal, your VSI could have some kinfd of restrictions, so please try doing the same OS reload using the control portal first.

Answer (score 0):

the error is clear your image is not compatible with your guest you need to pick another image template, one of the things you need to check is the sizes of the primary disks (the device0), if you are using an standard image template the size of the primary disk of the template must have the same size of the primary disk of your VSI. In case that your image template is a flex image you need to make sure that the primary disk of the flex image is less or equals to the size of the primary disk in your virtual guest.

Regards